# Save UIImage in Documents directory

Tags: ios, uiimage

I know this way to save image in document directory.

```
// Save image.
[UIImagePNGRepresentation(image) writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES];
```

But want to save `UIImage` in Document directory directly without converting it to `NSData`.  Is there any way?

Comment: Why? What's wrong with converting it to `NSData`? It's certainly makes it a much smaller file. Saving the raw bytes of the `UIImage` will be huge.

Comment: @rmaddy acutely i have to save 40+ images but it takes long time. Because 1st it convert UIImage in NSData then it write it to directory. 
So just to do fast processing save image, I am searching some alternative .

Comment: The delay is the time it takes to convert the uncompressed, raw `UIImage` data into the PNG format. Even if you want to write the raw, uncompressed `UIImage` data, you still need to write the data. Do some searching on accessing the data of a `UIImage`. Once you know how to access that data, it isn't too hard to write all of those bytes to a file. But those files will be huge and you may end up spending more time writing more data.

Comment: A UIImage _has_ to be converted to _some_ format for saving. What format did you have in mind?

Answer (score 1):

To save a UIImage as a file in an image format, use the [ImageIO framework](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/graphicsimaging/conceptual/ImageIOGuide/imageio_basics/ikpg_basics.html).

In this example, I save an image into the Application Support directory as a tiff (this is fastest because no compression is involved):

```
CGImageSourceRef src = // ... whatever, depends on how you got the image originally
NSFileManager* fm = [NSFileManager new];
NSURL* suppurl = [fm URLForDirectory:NSApplicationSupportDirectory
                            inDomain:NSUserDomainMask
                   appropriateForURL:nil
                              create:YES error:nil];
NSURL* tiff = [suppurl URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"mytiff.tiff"];
CGImageDestinationRef dest =
    CGImageDestinationCreateWithURL((__bridge CFURLRef)tiff,
                                    (CFStringRef)@"public.tiff", 1, nil);
CGImageDestinationAddImageFromSource(dest, src, 0, nil);
bool ok = CGImageDestinationFinalize(dest);
// error-checking omitted
CFRelease(src); CFRelease(dest);
```

Comment: @NiravD see https://github.com/mattneub/Programming-iOS-Book-Examples/blob/master/bk2ch23p829imageIO/ch36p1084imageIO/ViewController.swift